# how the interface works?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand how interfaces work. I have read basic interface tutorials online and watched a few videos so i do have a good idea of what a interface is and its advantages.

**Interface**

```
public interface UpyunFormApi {
@Description("上传文件")
@POST("/{bucket}")
@Multipart
public Request upload(@Path("bucket") String bucket, @Part("policy") PolicyPart policy,
        @Part("signature") SignaturePart signature, @Part("file") File file, OnRequestListener requestListener,
        OnResponseListener<UpyunFormEntity> responseListener, OnErrorListener errorListener);
```

**Code**

```
private UpyunFormApi formApi;
private void uploadAndPushTopic() {
        String bucket = UrlManager.getInstance().getUpyunImageBucket();
        String secret = UrlManager.getInstance().getUpyunImageSecret();

        for (File file : filearr) {
            PolicyPart policy = new PolicyPart(bucket);
            SignaturePart signature = new SignaturePart(policy, secret);
            formApi.upload(bucket, policy, signature, file, uploadRequestListener, uploadResponseListener,
                    uploadErrorListener);
        }
    }

    private OnRequestListener uploadRequestListener = new OnRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRequest(Request arg0) {
        }
    };

    private OnErrorListener uploadErrorListener = new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(LegolasException arg0) {
            }
    };

    private OnResponseListener<UpyunFormEntity> uploadResponseListener = new OnResponseListener<UpyunFormEntity>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(UpyunFormEntity arg0) {
            }
        }
    };
```

Why the Responselister works after "formApi.upload()" finished?And I can't find function definition.Help!
I don't understand the code

```
@Description("上传文件")
    @POST("/{bucket}")
    @Multipart
```

Comment: "I have read basic interface tutorials..." now read the documentation for the annotations you're using.

Comment: `Why the Responselister works after "formApi.upload()" finished?` - did you check for exceptions or errors to be thrown? Is there only one file in the array? I'd advice you to debug your code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> Make an interface like :

```
   public interface ChangeItemInterface {

        public void doChange(String anyValue);

    }
```

**In Adapter,**

> Intialize interface object like :

```
ChangeItemInterface changeItemInterface;
```

> In Adapter Constructor,

```
this.changeItemInterface = context;
```

> In Adapter, From any View Click :

```
AnyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 this.changeItemInterface.doChange("AnyValue");
                 // It will go to the Your Activity Overided method which is explained below this


            }
        });
```

> In Your Activity implement this interface like :

```
     public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ChangeItemInterface{

        /// You'll get override method of your interface, here your call back will come when from adapter click happen
         @Override
            public void doChange(String anyValue) {

              /// Here you can update any value in your activity !
            }

        }
```

Hope this demo help you to understand interface use !